# Translation of the phrase "I'm happy."

Tags: verbos, diferencias-regionales, cópulas

In the phrase:

> I'm happy

Which one of these is grammatically correct to translate the phrase, `ser` or `estar`?

> Soy feliz

or

> Estoy feliz

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the context of the question .

The verb "estar" in that phrase is commonly used for that particular moment.

> Estoy feliz. (*I am happy at the moment.*)

However, "ser" can be used for quality or character of a person.

> Soy feliz. (*I'm a happy person.*)

Answer (score 4):

In Spanish to talk about a feeling (happiness) you would use estar (denotes location or a state of being).

```
 Estoy ... contento (a)

 ...alegre

 ...feliz
```

all of which translate to about the same meaning so you could use all 3 interchangeably.

Happy Learning